# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation Stuck :

Tags: system-installation

Installation stuck after ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team :   Do not know what to do after that? Even tried mate , Xubuntu, Ubuntu 16.04.4 --- Every installation is struck .

Any links to overcome this issue and successfully install ubuntu. This is a Acer core i3 laptop and I am using ubuntu 14 till now.